# What Probabilistic Function to use

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math, probability-density

I want to probabilistically chose "n" edges from "e" edges_in_sorted_order in a vector.
But i want to use probability in choosing. And i also want not to choose big edges in the starting.

so its like giving more weightage to smaller edges in the starting, and as i take edges,
i would give more and more weightage to bigger remaining edges too.

what probabilistic function of n and e should i choose ?

```
while( edgesTaken < n ) {
     for each edge i and edgesTaken < n
         probability = pdf( edgesTaken, i)
         if ( prob > THRESHOLD )
              take the edge
 }
```

[image]

Comment: I looked at normal distribution but swapping x for i_edge and sigma^2 for edgesTaken, put the f(x) very small for large i_edge. Can it be CDF of normal distribution ?

Comment: It is not necessary that graphs should be like this only. It is just my representation. It should take care of above constraints of slowly giving more weightage to big edges

Comment: One (untested) possibility: Starting from edge `0`, take edge `i` with probability `((n-edgesTaken)/(e-i))**(1/7)`.  You can adjust the `7` at your leisure, higher values will favor lower valued edges.

Answer (score 0):

You need the quantile function for the distribution you want. Draw a random number using a standard generator to give you q uniformally distributed in [0, 1). Then call the quantile function with q as the parameter. The resulting random set will have the required distribution.

Comment: where are my n and e fitting into it ?

Comment: Your quantile function will be a function of n and e.

Comment: from my learnings i found that quantile gives us the point where given a distribution and a percentage of CDF, it tells the point where CDF crosses that percentage. I can not understand how to apply your q , n and e here. ?

Answer (score 0):

The probability that the first edge is 1 is choose(n-1,e-1)/choose(n,e).

More generally, the probability that the first edge is k is 
[choose(n-k,e-1)/choose(n,e)] * 1/k

You also might want the probability that there is exactly one edge in 1-k:
[choose(n-k,e-1)/choose(n,e)]

From here I think you can wrap things up!

P.S. Just to explain, the three functions give the ratio of the number of ways to pick edges that satisfy their condition, to choose(n,e) which is the number of ways to pick e edges from n.

Comment: n is always smaller or equal to e here.

Comment: what is k in your solution ?

Comment: This has `n` and `e` switched from the OP (to be fair, `n` is more commonly a total, not `e`).  `k` is the first edge chosen.  But I don't think that this favors small edges.

Comment: Yep, I switched n and e. oops. I'll leave the post as is. This doesn't favor any edges, just gives the probability that the first edge is k assuming all edges are chosen with equal probability. Doing that is enough to make the first edge likely to be small as long as multiple edges are chosen. Unclear to me of the OP wants something fancier.

Comment: I think OP wants that the probability that edge `k` is chosen to be greater than the probability that edge `k+1` is chosen.  But it would be nice to have something more explanatory than that sketch.